# SerialPort.GetPortNames throws exception on Android

Tags: android, .net-core, serial-port, maui

I'm writing a MAUI App using .Net 8, and I need to connect to a serial port.  However, when calling the static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() method, I get a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException thrown.

There seem to be a number of people that are using this on Android devices, however I could not find a definitive statement that the System.IO.Ports library can be used on Android.

Can somebody please unequivocally state that it works (or does not work) on Android?

My target Android version has to be Android 7 (API 24).

Comment: what is the InnerException?

Comment: @Jason - Dang, that's the answer.  After adding code to catch the exception it showed that it's PlatformNotSupportedException: Enumeration of of serial port names is not supported on the current platform.